# Join array if duplicate value (Laravel)

Tags: mysql, laravel

I try to join duplicates value in array, but if joined array has different values, that should create another array automaticly.

this is my code, using query builder on laravel

```php
DB::table('users')
    ->select(
        'users.id',
        'users.first_name',
        'users.last_name',
        'users.no_rekening',
        'users.empid',
        'users.no_rekening',
        'users.detail',
        'users.is_approve',
        'users.is_active',
        'karyawan_project.project_id',
        'project.nama as nama_project',
        'client.nama as nama_client'
    )->leftJoin(
        'karyawan_project',
        'users.id','=','karyawan_project.karyawan_id',
        'client.nama '
    )->join(
        'project',
        'karyawan_project.project_id','=','project.id'
    )->join('spk','project.spk_id','=','spk.id')
    ->join('client','spk.client_id','=','client.id')
    ->where('tipe', 2)
    ->whereIn('is_active', [1,0,2])
    ->orderBy('users.id')
    ->get();
```

and the result

```
1 => {#747 ▼
  +"id": 17
  +"first_name": "Dadan R"
  +"last_name": "Hadiansyah"
  +"no_rekening": "1150006713467"
  +"empid": "01180104"
  +"detail": ""
  +"is_approve": 1
  +"is_active": 1
  +"project_id": 4
  +"nama_project": "Driver Manager & Operasional"
  +"nama_client": "PT. TRANSPORTASI GAS INDONESIA"
}
2 => {#797 ▼
  +"id": 18
  +"first_name": "Setia"
  +"last_name": "Darma"
  +"no_rekening": "1150006713475"
  +"empid": "01180105"
  +"detail": null
  +"is_approve": 1
  +"is_active": 1
  +"project_id": 181
  +"nama_project": "Driver Operasional"
  +"nama_client": "PT. TRANSPORTASI GAS INDONESIA"
}
3 => {#790 ▼
  +"id": 18
  +"first_name": "Setia"
  +"last_name": "Darma"
  +"no_rekening": "1150006713475"
  +"empid": "01180105"
  +"detail": null
  +"is_approve": 1
  +"is_active": 1
  +"project_id": 4
  +"nama_project": "Driver Manager & Operasional"
  +"nama_client": "PT. TRANSPORTASI GAS INDONESIA"
}
4 => {#796 ▼
  +"id": 18
  +"first_name": "Setia"
  +"last_name": "Darma"
  +"no_rekening": "1150006713475"
  +"empid": "01180105"
  +"detail": null
  +"is_approve": 1
  +"is_active": 1
  +"project_id": 6
  +"nama_project": "PENGAMANAN STATION MBK"
  +"nama_client": "PT. PERMATA GRAHA NUSANTARA"
}
5 => {#757 ▼
  +"id": 19
  +"first_name": "Ardian"
  +"last_name": "Ismail"
  +"no_rekening": "1150004433837"
  +"empid": "01180106"
  +"detail": null
  +"is_approve": 1
  +"is_active": 0
  +"project_id": 4
  +"nama_project": "Driver Manager & Operasional"
  +"nama_client": "PT. TRANSPORTASI GAS INDONESIA"
```

the result has duplicate values where id = 18 and different nama_project

what I want is, id where has duplicate value join into one array
and also nama_project with different value

like

```
1 => {#747 ▼
  +"id": 17
  +"first_name": "Dadan R"
  +"last_name": "Hadiansyah"
  +"no_rekening": "1150006713467"
  +"empid": "01180104"
  +"detail": ""
  +"is_approve": 1
  +"is_active": 1
  +"project_id": 4
  +"nama_project": "Driver Manager & Operasional"
  +"nama_client": "PT. TRANSPORTASI GAS INDONESIA"
}
2 => {#797 ▼
  +"id": 18
  +"first_name": "Setia"
  +"last_name": "Darma"
  +"no_rekening": "1150006713475"
  +"empid": "01180105"
  +"detail": null
  +"is_approve": 1
  +"is_active": 1
  +"project_id": 181
  +"nama_project": ▼{
                 +"Driver Operasional"
                 +"Driver Manager & Operasional"
                 +"PENGAMANAN STATION MBK"
               }
  +"nama_client": "PT. TRANSPORTASI GAS INDONESIA"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer

```
$data = DB::table('users')
                  // ->with(['history'=>function($kar){
                  //             $kar->with('project.spk.client')->select('project_id','karyawan_id')->where('status',1);
                  //  }])
                        ->select('users.id','users.first_name','users.last_name','users.no_rekening','users.empid','users.no_rekening',
                                 'users.detail','users.is_approve','users.is_active','karyawan_project.project_id','karyawan_project.status',
                                 'project.nama as nama_project',
                                 'client.description as nama_client')
                        ->leftJoin('karyawan_project', 'users.id','=','karyawan_project.karyawan_id')
                        ->join('project','karyawan_project.project_id','=','project.id')
                        ->join('spk','project.spk_id','=','spk.id')
                        ->join('client','spk.client_id','=','client.id')
                        ->where('tipe', 2)->whereIn('is_active',[1,0,2])->orderBy('users.id')->get()
               ;

               $previous_id = 0;

               foreach($data as $key => $user){
                     $user->merged = [];
                     $user->project = '<b>'.$user->nama_client. '</b> ' . $user->nama_project;
                     if ($previous_id == $user->id) {

                           $minKey = $key-1;

                           if (!empty($data[$minKey]->merged)) {

                                 if ($user->status == 1) {
                                       array_push($user->merged, $user->project);
                                 }

                                    $user->merged = array_merge($user->merged, $data[$minKey]->merged);


                             }else {
                                   if ($user->status == 1) {
                                          array_push($user->merged, $user->project, $data[$minKey]->project);
                                   }

                            }
                       unset($data[$minKey]);

                       }else {
                               if ($user->status == 1) {
                                     array_push($user->merged,$user->project);
                               }
                       }
                       $previous_id = $user->id;
               }


            $data = $data->sortBy('first_name');
```

Comment: this is the query what i want


select us.id, us.first_name, us.last_name, 
group_concat(IF (kp.status = 1,  CONCAT('<b>',c.description,'</b> - ',pr.nama), NULL) SEPARATOR ', ') as project
from roles r
left join role_user ru on ru.role_id=r.id
left join users us on us.id = ru.user_id
left join karyawan_project kp on us.id = kp.karyawan_id 
left join project pr on kp.project_id = pr.id
left join spk spk on spk.id = pr.spk_id
left join client c on c.id = spk.client_id
WHERE r.name = 'karyawan'
group by us.id  
ORDER BY `us`.`id`  ASC

Answer (score 1):

Since you have ordered the result by users.id. Let's assume you save the result in `$users`, then you could do something like:

```
$usersWithMergedProjects = [];
$previous_id = 0;
foreach($users as $user){
    if($user->id == $previous_id){
        array_push($usersWithMergedProjects[$user->id]->nama_projects, $user->nama_project);
    } else {
        $usersWithMergedProjects[$user->id] = $user;
        $usersWithMergedProjects[$user->id]->nama_projects = [];
        array_push($usersWithMergedProjects[$user->id]->nama_projects, $user->nama_project);

    }
    $previous_id = $user->id;
    unset($usersWithMergedProjects[$user->id]->nama_project);
}
```

note: If you got any error with this, please take a screenshot of the errors.

Comment: thats not join an array

Comment: @dennisramli, I've edited my answer, let me know if you got any errors.

Comment: "array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given"

Comment: which line @den?

Comment: array_push($userWithMergedProjects[$user->id]['nama_project'], $user->nama_project); this line

I think $previous_id = $user->id; this code should be placed outside if else, but inside foreach

Comment: @dennisramli, I've updated my answer. I've also tested the code.